# ansible pipelining mode with shell script that requires tty

Tags: debian, pipelining, ansible

I am using ansible to install node.js and npm on Debian wheezy VMs following the steps in the Backports section of [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) .

The following playbook task used to work nicely with conventional ansible ssh mode.

```
- name: install npm
shell: curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh creates=/usr/bin/npm
```

Until I tried to enable pipelining of ansible 1.5. now it fails with:

```
npm-install-18570.sh: 246: npm-install-18570.sh: cannot open /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

The downloaded shellscript install.sh references /dev/tty in line 246 and therefore fails when executed with ansible in pipelining mode.

Can I disable pipelining just for this one task?
Is there another option?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no option to disable `pipelining` for a single task AFAIK. Keep in mind that Ansible 1.5 is still in development stages.

However, as a workaround you can run your task on a separate playbook passing the `pipelining=False` environment variable to override the value of your `ansible.cfg` file:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./your-inventory-file -e "pipelining=False" your-no-pipeline-playbook.yml
```

This as per described here (from Ansible docs):

> Ansible also allows configuration of settings via environment
>   variables. If these environment variables are set, they will override
>   any setting loaded from the configuration file. These variables are
>   for brevity not defined here, but look in ‘constants.py’ in the source
>   tree if you want to use these. They are mostly considered to be a
>   legacy system as compared to the config file, but are equally valid.

and here:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/constants.py

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for ansible 1.8.2. I had to use `ANSIBLE_SSH_PIPELINING=False ansible-playbook -i ./your-inventory-file your-no-pipeline-playbook.yml`